# storing returned object from useRef in redux state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, next.js

i have a question.
im creating a music platform(like spotify) with `next js` and to manage states, i use `redux toolkit`. to play a music, i added `audio` in a component that has some components to change the music time or volume or etc. to change the volume or time or etc, i used `useRef` hook and i change the music time almost like this(this is a component that return some elements for large devices only and if the device is small, audio style will be `display: none;`):

```
//inside a component(for example AudioLarge.jsx)
const audioRef = useRef()

useEffect(() => {
   //if ref is ready, change the time
   if(audioRef.current) audioRef.current.currentTime = 50;
}, [])

return (
<>
   <audio src={source} ref={audioRef} />
</>
)
```

the problem starts here. i want to access the ref from `AudioLarge.jsx` in `AudioSmall.jsx` component that returns some elements for small devices. i have a solution for this. i can store the music ref in redux state. but is it ok? is it a good solution for this? does it make problems in future? is there a better solution to access the music ref globally? thanks for helping :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can store it in redux store...
you can store it in any state management system from context api to redux

but the best way is to declare reference to it in a reducer and means to updated its state right thru action right there in that reducer...
i.e its own reducer to keep your code neat

```
//in your page

import { useRef } from 'react';
.......
const audioref = useRef(null);
<audio ref = {audioref} />
```

somewhere in your codes you store the reference in your store thru action

```
<button onClick = {() => addAudioRef(audioref)}>play</button>
```

in your reducer

```
switch(state.action) {
   ....

   case 'audioref-added':
      return {...state, audioref : payload.audioref.current.play()}
   case 'audioref-stoped':
      return {...state, audioref : state.audioref.current.stop()}
   ....
}
```

Comment: thank you very much! your right. for example to play music, i can create a function in reducer property of slice, and then play the music there. is it your point?

Comment: i get your point, let me edit my post to clarify

Comment: oh! so you meant this! but i use redux toolkit and it is really easier to do something like this. by the way, thank you for your answer. i check you as the correct answer :)

Comment: thanks... i think i need to start using toolkit for redux

Comment: makes life easier

Comment: Sure! It doesnt have much things to learn. A very good thing in redux toolkit is that you dont need to name your actions. Redex toolkit does for you! And you can split your actions to slices and keep your codes very cleaner than when using redux. I really suggest you to use it :)